# Liftability of varieties, after fpqc base change

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, birational-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over a finite field, with a closed immersion to some other smooth projective variety $S$, **with $S$ liftable**.

Suppose there exists an fpqc cover $S'\to S$, such that $X\times_SS'$ can be lifted to mixed characteristic.

> Can $X$ be lifted to mixed characteristic?

For example, suppose $S = \mathbb{P}^n$, and $X\to S$ is a projective embedding. Take $S^{\rm perf}$, the perfection of $S$ (inverse limit along the absolute Frobenius map). Then $S' := S^{\rm perf}\to S$ is an fpqc cover.

> Say $X_{S'}$ is liftable to mixed characteristic. Is $X$?
>   Equivalently, do obstructions to liftability of $X$ give obstructions to liftability of $X_{S'}$?

My guess is that the answer is no. If anyone sees an obstruction to liftability of $X_{S'}$ coming from non-liftability of $X$, that is what I am looking for.

Comment: No; take $X=S$ to be any non-liftable smooth variety and $S'$ any affine cover of $X$.  Smooth affines always lift, so this gives a counterexample.

Comment: @DanielLitt $S$ is assumed to be liftable. I forgot this in the general question, but this is clear in the example, since $\mathbb{P}^n$ is liftable

Comment: Ok, then take X any smooth non-liftable projective variety, S to be projective space, and S’ any affine cover of projective space...

Comment: @DanielLitt How does this give a counterexample to the OP's question about the choice $S' = (\mathbf{P}^n)^{perf}\to S$?
I agree yours gives a counterexample to the more general question.

Comment: It doesn’t; but I think the answer to the second question is also negative.  Isn’t $X_{S’}$ just the same as $X^{perf}$ in this case? But perfect schemes always lift, so again one can take X to be anything that doesn’t lift...

Comment: @DanielLitt That's my concern. There's a map over $S'$, from $X^{perf}$ to $X_{S'}$: the relative Frobenius $F_{X/S'}$. Why should that be an isomorphism? In the affine case, if $R$ is a perfect $\mathbf{F}_p$ algebra, not all ideals give a perfect quotient of $R$. Maybe something about $X\to S$ being a closed immersion and $S$ being the **projective space**?

Comment: The map $X^{\rm{pf}}\to X_{S^{\rm{pf}}}$ over $S^{\rm{pf}}$ is not an isomorphism when $X\ne S$ (assume $X$ and $S$ are connected, so irreducible): $X^{\rm{pf}}$ is reduced but the closed subscheme $X\times_S S^{\rm{pf}}$ of $S^{\rm{pf}}$ is non-reduced when $X\ne S$. Indeed, since $F_S$ is faithfully flat it suffices to show  $X\times_{S,F_S} S$ is non-reduced if $X\ne S$. This is finite flat radiciel of degree $p^{\dim S}$ over $X$, and if reduced it would (by irreducibility) be integral with function field inside $k(X)^{1/p}$, so $p^{\dim X}= [k(X)^{1/p}:k(X)]\ge p^{\dim S}$, contradiction.